# JoinOverQuery with multiple tables containing lists

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Trying to generate nhibernate query for a relationship that has lists of values which makes using alias tricky.

A User can have multiple Roles or Tenants, I want to select all Users that have a specific role and a specific tenant.

What I was doing so far isn't working:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<User>();

query.JoinQueryOver<Role>(x => x.Roles)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Id == roleId);

query.JoinQueryOver<Tenant>(x => x.Tenants)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Abbreviation == Context.Abbreviation);
```

Any suggestions for this? When I tried to use an alias I ran into a problem that I need to use a .Contains method and I don't think nhibernate/sql can figure out what to do with that.

This is the error I am getting when I hit the first JoinQueryOver

```
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "variable 'x' of type 'Role' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined",
"exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Or what explicit error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, should have done that initially. Threw it up now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in this case, must be like this:

```
query.JoinQueryOver<Role>(x => x.Roles)
    //.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Id == roleId)
    .Where(x => x.Id == roleId)
    ;
```

The `WhereRestrictionOn` could be used for scenarios like this:

```
.WhereRestrictionOn(() => role.Name)
    .IsLike("Admin", MatchMode.Start)
```

But I would suggest, if possible, to use the subquery. *(if the collection item has reference to parent)*

```
User user = null;
Role role = null;

// the subselect, filtering the Roles, returning the user ID
var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Role>(() => role)
    .Where(() => role.ID == roleId)
    .Select(c => role.User.ID);


// the query of the User, 
// where at least one role fits the above subquery
var query = session.QueryOver<User>(() => user)
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereProperty(() => user.Id)
    .In(subQuery);
```

Among many other advantages, this approach will give us a flat root `User` table, so we can apply `Skip()` and `Take()` for correct paging...

Comment: Thanks, you were right about my misuse of WhereRestrictionOn

Comment: Great if that helped. Enjoy NHibernate, awesome tool ;)